# SF novel about a vicar meeting an alien machine

Tags: story-identification, novel

The book I’m looking for is a novelisation of an event that is said to have actually happened.

I was reading a book that collected together strange facts. One was about a country vicar or parson who when walking through the woods, came across an alien machine.

The vicar told nobody about this during his lifetime. He just wrote it down in his diary which was not read until after his death.

I believe this story was novelised. Does anyone know the name of this novel, or the name of the vicar so that I can research him?

Comment: What book were you reading that contained this "strange fact"?

Answer (score 3):

I'm strongly reminded of an old short story, from one of Judith Merril's "Years Best" collections for the 1960s called "Far From Home" in which a Catholic priest in Ireland hears the confession of a drunk who has a strange tiny humanoid corpse in his house. Turns out, the alien landed near the mans house and in his drunken imaginings, he capture him in the belief that the alien is in fact a leprechaun. Struggling with the creature, the old drunk opens the faceplate of the alien's suit and the being dies: the ship it arrived in takes off automatically, the noise and light from which attracts the Priest from nearby to investigate. The story ends on a poetic note as the priest speculates on whether this creature, who resembles a Fae or fairy, might not have been from earth in ancient times, giving rise to the legends and becoming adapted to another world after vacating Earth and hopes that "the dark peat soil we laid are visitor in was not, to him, so alien after all."

( The title is the same as another story which features a leprechaun, a whale and a swimming pool in New Mexico. )